# How to clone a Select2 control loaded with Django and Python?

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-select2

I'm trying to clone a select inside a div. But when i clone the element, the Select2 element doesn't have the loaded values by the Django code. How can i clone my div with all the Select2 element values? When i clone, it clones, but the selects are not showing the values. Thank you so much.

```
<script>
counter = 0
function addTopic(){
  $( "#select" ).clone().appendTo( "#trying" );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="addTopic()">Add Topic</button>

<form action="{% url 'testing_show' %}">
<div id="trying">
    <div id="select">
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
        {% for taf_doc in taf_documents %}
            <option value="{{ taf_doc.id }}">{{ taf_doc.taf.nom }}</option>
        {% endfor %}

        </select>

        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
        {% for ue_doc in ue_documents %}
            <option value="{{ ue_doc.id }}">{{ ue_doc.ue.nom}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
```

This is the header :

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
});//document ready
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here
I had to first 'destroy' the existing select2

`$("#parentDiv").children("select").djangoSelect2("destroy")`

clone the div, increment the ids and remove the select2-container that was a child of the actual select2 select element (so when we re-init the select2, we don't get duplicates)

```
let form_count = 1

function cloneAndChangeIds(wrapper) {

          // clone the wrapper
          let clone = wrapper.cloneNode(true);
          clone.id ="form_" + form_count;

          // add text to the `for` attribute of every label
          const labels = Array.from(clone.querySelectorAll('label'));
          labels.forEach(label => {
            label.htmlFor += "_" + form_count;
          });

          // add text to the `id` attribute of every select and input
          const items = Array.from(clone.querySelectorAll('select, input'));
          items.forEach(select => {
              select.id += "_" + form_count
              if(select.hasAttribute('data-select2-id')){
                  select.setAttribute('data-select2-id', select.id)
              }
          });

          const s2items = Array.from(clone.querySelectorAll('.select2-container'));
          s2items.forEach(select => {
              select.remove()
          });
          return clone;
        }

const container = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
const original_form = document.getElementById('original_form');
```

and then append it back to the parentDiv and re-init the djangoSelect2 on both select2 elements

```
addForm = () => {
            form_count = form_count + 1
$("#original_form").children("select").djangoSelect2("destroy")
            const clone = cloneAndChangeIds(original_form)
            container.appendChild(clone);
            $("#id_segment_"+ form_count).djangoSelect2();
            $("#parentDiv").children("select").djangoSelect2();
}
```

Apologies for my terribad javascript code styling